# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument ...when eval() function is used

Tags: javascript, parsing, syntax-error

```js
let html = "Math.sqrt(5**2-1)";

try{
    console.log(eval(html));
}

catch(error){
    console.log(error);
}
```

here i got an error saying missing ) after the argument list
where as when directly the expression is typed the answer is showing

[image]

Comment: Where are you executing this? I get the correct result in the latest Firefox and Chrome

Comment: That's why eval is evil.

Comment: This snippet actually works.

Comment: Don't use eval, ever!

Comment: Click the link VM252:6 you will see the exactly line of code that fails

Comment: @lastr2d2 it should be `console.log(eval(html));` as it says third line. It's the third one from the whole snippet.

Comment: @Adrian Brand...is there any alternative..? because i am getting the same error with new Function()

Comment: Just use Math.sqrt(5**2-1) Why do you need to wrap it in an eval?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your snippet and it works, however.

Dont use eval! Its evil. Us rather `new Function`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

```js
let statement = "Math.sqrt(5**2-1)";

let result = new Function(`return ${statement}`)();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why would you advertise `new Function` over simply `Math.sqrt(5**2-1)` - the code, rather than the string?

Comment: @VLAZ i advertise `new Function` over `eval()`. Sure he could go with `Math.sqrt()`. But he used `eval()` for some reason

Comment: yes i actually had to parse an expression from a string as a part of the project i was assigned..

Comment: the snippet does show the answer but why was i getting error in the console as in the image...? please answer if possible..

Comment: @Nav i cannot tell. for me it worked with no problem and i dont see a problem in the snippet